# Whose definition of "science fiction" is this?

Tags: science-fiction-genre, quotes

Sometime in the last quarter of the 20<sup>th</sup> century (or just possibly in the very early 2000s) I read somewhere the following [definition of science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_science_fiction) (not word-for-word, I paraphrase):

> Science fiction is fiction designed to appeal to youths with an interest in science and technology.

I would like to know the source and the exact wording of that definition. I'm pretty sure that I read it in the editorial matter of some sci-fi anthology. Of course that definition may have been repeated or quoted elsewhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not quite the same as the definition in the question, but it certainly struck me as a close one

> I might define science fiction as fantasy fiction designed to appeal to those with a knowledge and interest in science

This is from the Paper 'Mathematics in Science Fiction' by Alex Kasman from the College of Charleston in 2004.  It can be found at [this link](http://kasmana.people.cofc.edu/MATHFICT/sf-mathhoriz.pdf).

It doesn't mention youth or technology and adds the fantasy element, but other than that it is remarkably similar!

Comment: @user14111 I found it by searching the web actually.  Really glad I found it though; excellent definition!

Comment: Coming to this late, but doesn't this beg the question, "What is fantasy fiction?"